# Error al imprimir un resultado en consola en Android Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar en Android con el lenguaje de programcion Kotlin  queria saber si me ayudan

Tengo un problema a la hora imprir por consola una resta le muestro  el codigo:

```
print("Escribe le primer valor: ")
val num1 = readLine()!!.toInt() 
print("Escribe el segundo valor: ")
val num2 = readLine()!!.toInt()
print( "${num1} - ${num2}" + num1 - num2  ) => el error me lo marca en el segundo menos
```

gracia por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

los ***string templates*** en kotlin se pueden realizar mediante el signo `$` en una variable pero para acceder a un objeto y hacer operaciones se utiliza la expresión `${}`
así que deberías colocarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
print("${num1} - ${num2} =" + " ${num1 - num2}")
```

o tambien

```
print("${num1} - ${num2} = " + (num1 - num2))
```

Comment: gracias buen dia o noches  depende donde estes

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la respuesta y es agragar parentesis de esta manera

ANTES con el  error
println("${num1} - ${num2} = " + num1 - num2)

AHORA con la sulución
print("${num1} - ${num2} = " + (num1 - num2))

Answer (score 0):

Agrega entre parentesis la operacion de las variables, para que concatene la cadena con el valor de la operacion:

```
print( "${num1} - ${num2}" + (num1 - num2)  )
```

còdigo:

```
print("Escribe le primer valor: ")
val num1 = readLine()!!.toInt() 
print("Escribe el segundo valor: ")
val num2 = readLine()!!.toInt()
print( "${num1} - ${num2}" + (num1 - num2)  )
```